# How to clear the default gateway of a network interface (nic) using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, wmi

I'm currently changing the default gateway using:

```
ManagementBaseObject gateway = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
gateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { "192.168.0.1" };
var r = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", gateway, null);
```

What I want to know is how can I clear the gateway, I tried empty string and null values as parameters instead of "192.168.0.1" but didn't work. Anyone has any ideas about this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the return value of InvokeMethod?

Comment: Well my first try was passing in an empty string array like the answer by @Hand-E-Food here and that sets 0.0.0.0 on the gateway (I mean I see 0.0.0.0 when I check it using Network and Sharing Center normally in Windows) but 0.0.0.0 is the same as clearing it? Then I tried using `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" gateway=none` and it worked like I really wanted, empty instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: I tried your `netsh` command and got an invalid syntax error.  I'm using _Windows 7_.  It seems to require `source=dhcp|static`.  Try your command again and then type `netsh interface ipv4 show address name="Local Area Connection"` to see if the IP address or DHCP enabled settings have changed.

Comment: Having the same problem... Setting the InParameters to Null, or Empty, doesnt put back the DHCP enabled gateway that i over wrote. I am trying to stay away from netsh. I am working with Remote Servers and i dont want to invoke a process or a psexec session.

Answer (score 1):

Set your gateway to the same IP as the static IP for the NIC. Not sure why but this clears the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of configurations that will result in the invocation failing, such as DHCP being enabled, that are not related to WMI.  The code itself is probably fine, assuming `mo` is a Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration instance.

If you haven't already, you may want to use the value of `r.Properties["returnvalue"].Value` to get the return value, and check that the return value is what you expect [(MSDN ref)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The error code should narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the gateway to an empty array.

```
ManagementBaseObject gateway = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
gateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] {};
var r = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", gateway, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried that and it sets 0.0.0.0 and I wanted it cleared, like nothing :) and then I tried the netsh command like I commented on my question.

Answer (score 0):

This method only works when the Network Interface Card (NIC) is in the static IP mode.
To clear the gateway, set your gateway to the same IP you use on EnableStatic.

Please see "Remark" of the follow page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setgateways-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration